# Try to click on "a" button using selenium but It navigates to the "href" URL instead of showing pop-up

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a python script. When it tries to click on "https://www.etsy.com/" site language change button using selenium It navigates to "href" URL. but I want it to show the pop-up.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19gNb.png)

This is how the code look like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.etsy.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[id=locale-picker-trigger]'))).click()
driver.close()
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use element_to_be_clickable() instead, and js executor to click.

```
driver.get("https://www.etsy.com/")
lang=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[id=locale-picker-trigger]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lang)
```

---

Update

```
driver.get("https://www.etsy.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(., 'Accept')]"))).click()
lang=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[id=locale-picker-trigger]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lang)
```

browser snapshot

[image]

Comment: It is not worked

Comment: @suraj : strange!! this is working for me. anyways try to click on cookie first and then do the same. use updated answer.

Comment: Yes, It navigates to the above browser snapshot page, but I want to see the pop-up. https://i.stack.imgur.com/19gNb.png

Comment: Thanks, It worked, but to run this properly, first need to scroll down.